# What is XE_FILE_TARGET_TVF wait type in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm experiencing periodical Azure SQL Database connection slow downs. As recommended in [Wait statistics, or please tell me where it hurts](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/) article I ran `sys.dm_db_wait_stats` (analogue of `sys.dm_os_wait_stats` for Azure SQL Database) aggregation script which show me that longest waits are of type `XE_FILE_TARGET_TVF`. Average wait time is *54 seconds*.

`XE_FILE_TARGET_TVF` didn't mentioned in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269834.aspx#WaitTypes) as in any other online resources that I know. I suspect that "XE" means "Extended Events", "TVF" is "table-valued functions", "FILE_TARGET" is probably indicator that something is being written to some file.

So, what kind of wait it is?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Azure SQL Database Query Performance Insight](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-query-performance/) for troubleshooting SQL Azure DBs. To begin with, wait stats alone are not a correct performance troubleshooting approach. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) for a more thorough approach, learn to analyze also where the CPU is spent, not only where the elapsed time is spent waiting. Aggregate wait stats are often misleading, filtering out the 'benign' wait stats is a chasing the red lights game.

Unfortunately not everything is actionable in SQL Azure DB environment. Start with the Query Performance Insight to see if you can correlate the performance issues with queries issued by your app. Use the [SQL Database Index Advisor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-index-advisor/) to get index recommendations for your workload.

If you cannot find the application problems and suspect this is caused by the platform, you will have to open a support case. Twitting @AzureSupport is very effective in getting help.

To answer your question: a lot of Azure SQL DB monitoring relies on Extended Events and they store data to files. This specific wait stat is unlikely to be related to the cause of your performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's a async process so possibly nothing to worry around and could be a red herring. However I think this is a fabric related task behind the DB. Does this event seem to be consistently causing you issues?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is the real cause of slow downs. But I'm experience them constantly, one time an hour, sometimes connection takes for about 40 seconds.

Comment: I can't find anything specific about it to be honest which is a little disappointing. Only thing I can find is similar to what I've said already on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/sqltomato/status/651330177876774912).